# How can I cast a object which is instantiated by reflection to its real type?

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection, c#-3.0, system.reflection

Recently I'm developing a tiny framework for myself, 
and I met this problem:
How can I do things like follow:

```
void object CreateDictionary(Type dictionaryType)
{
    object dict = dictionaryType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).Invoke(new object[] {});
    // Cast dict to its real type here so that I can add key-value-pairs to it.
    ...
}
```

The dictionaryType is the type of some kind of Dictionary, and is got via reflection.
I have no idea about the full type because I don't know the generic attributes until runtime.

I've also tried changing the declaration `object dict` to `var dict`, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. But, you know that this is some kind of Dictionary, so you can cast it to IDictionary and use methods of IDictionary.

```
object CreateDictionary(Type dictionaryType)
{
    object dict = dictionaryType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).Invoke(new object[] {});
    var idictionary = (IDictionary)dict;
    idictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

If your all this dictionaries is inherited from one class, you can cast it to this class and use methods of this class.

By the way, it is simpler to get instance of Type through:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Thank you, Kirill.
But IDictionary also requires generic attributes.

Comment: There is nongeneric IDictionary

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to solve this problem at last.
Finally I noticed that what I want to do is not about casting, 
but calling method. 
Maybe there are better solutions than mine.
Anyway, I'd like to share my solution.

First, create an extension class for object (this is weird though):

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static object InvokeInstanceMethod(this object invoker, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = invoker.GetType().GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] paramInfos = method.GetParameters();
            if (method.Name == methodName && paramInfos.Length == parameters.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!paramInfos[i].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(parameters[i].GetType()))
                    {
                        throw new MissingMethodException();
                    }
                }
                return method.Invoke(invoker, parameters);
            }
        }
        throw new MissingMethodException();
    }
}
```

This extension method allows me to call methods like this:

```
anyInstance.InvokeInstanceMethod("MethodName", param1, param2, ...);
```

Because all types, excluding Object itself, are derived from Object, this method can be cal on any instance of any type.

Then I use this method:

```
object dict = dictionaryType.CreateInstance(); // The method CreateInstance() is also an extension
dict.InvokeInstanceMethod("Add", key, val);
```